# Prove that the induced map is of degree n

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Let $P(z)$ be a complex polynomial of degree n.
$$P:S^2 \rightarrow S^2 $$ 
$S^2 - p_0 \cong C$ (stereographic projection) and $P(\infty)=\infty$.
I'd like to prove that $P_{*}:H_2(S^2) \rightarrow H_2(S^2) $ is of degree n.
Honestly I only have a very dim idea how to do it. I quess I should use the fact that if $D=P^{-1}(P(Z))$ where $Z$ is a set of zero's of $P^{'}(z)$ then $P:C-D \rightarrow C -P(Z)$ is a covering of degree n.Combine it with the naturality of Hurewicz homomorphism in dimension 1.
And use Meyer -Vietoris sequence for $A=S^2 - D$ and $B=S^2 - \infty$ :

$$0\rightarrow H_2(S^2) \rightarrow H_1(C-D)$$
Then use the naturality of that sequence and examine commutative diagram:
$$0\rightarrow H_2(S^2) \rightarrow H_1(C-D)$$
$$0\rightarrow H_2(S^2) \rightarrow H_1(C-D)$$
(I can't really show it but each column is connected by $P_{*}$)

$C-D$ is homotopy equivalent to a wedge sum of circles and intitively locally a polynomial $P(z)$ sends a generator $\alpha$ of a circle to $\alpha^{n}$.
I can't really come to a conclusion so any help will be very appreciated.

Comment: So actually this idea works well for  simple polynomials $z^n$. What' s left is to show that a polynomial of degree n is homotopic ( on a two - sphere) to a polynomial $z^n$, but unfortunately I don' t see why any polynomial shoyld not be homotopic to a linear one.